# Adding a column that starts from 0 and produces sequential numbers per individual

Tags: r

I have a data set with multiple observations per individual, that all cover the same distance i.e. 20 micrometers, each individual has a range of 31 to 35 observations over these 20 micrometers.
The main problem that this way, all individuals have different `Dist_micm` start points. I want to make them all start at 1 or 0, in order to be able to plot all of them together.

```
df

ID    Dist_micm  Conc
1_29  56.18       3514.919
1_29  56.75       3507.629
.     .            .
1_29  76.01       3495.644
1_29  76.18       3400.644
3_18  105.25      2873.534
3_18  105.83      2879.544
 .     .           .
3_18  125.83      2905.698
```

I tried binning the `Dist_micm` column using the following code:

```
df_bin <- df %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(Dist_bin=ntile(Dist_micm, n=20))%>%
ungroup()
```

Which gave me this:

```
df_bin

ID    Dist_micm   Conc     Dist_bin
1_29  56.18       3514.919  1
1_29  56.75       3507.629  1
.     .            .        .
1_29  76.01       3495.644  19
1_29  76.18       3400.644  20
3_18  105.25      2873.534  1
3_18  105.83      2879.544  1
 .     .           .        .
3_18  124.03      2895.798  19
3_18  125.83      2905.698  20
```

This is sort of half-way to what I need, because I would prefer if each row had a unique `Dist`, more similar to the original variable `Dist_micm`, something like this:

```
df_desired

ID    Dist_micm   Conc     Dist
1_29  56.18       3514.919  1.18
1_29  56.75       3507.629  1.75
.     .            .        .
1_29  76.01       3495.644  19.01
1_29  76.18       3400.644  20.18
3_18  105.25      2873.534  1.25
3_18  106.03      2879.544  1.63
 .     .           .        .
3_18  124.03      2895.798  19.03
3_18  125.83      2905.698  20.01
```

I don't really mind what form the numbers in the new `Dist` column take, as long as they are sequential, per each individual, and start from 0 or 1 and finish at 20, the above is just an example.

Many thanks for any ideas to solve this!

Comment: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Dist_new = Dist_micm - min(Dist_micm))`?

Comment: Perhaps I don't see the big picture, but why do you want/need `Dist` to be unique across all `ID`s? That seems an arbitrary constraint, and it modifies/changes data by doing so in ways that may not be consistent (or necessary).

Comment: Apologies, I didn't make it clear, it doesn't have to be unique for all individuals, just that they are unique within each individual

Comment: Though I understand the concept, I don't understand the utility or even "data honesty" of doing that. What's the rationale for changing the data somewhat arbitrarily or randomly?

Comment: The rationale is that the Dist_micm is from a larger transect, i.e. a transect that started before the point in which I am interested in, as this was done by hand, in order to not miss the point of interest, the transect was started in different places for different individuals. The start point was calculated based on measurement of the distance from the start of the transect to the point of interest. Therefore, different individuals have "different" start points. In reality those start points represent the same first 20 micrometers for all individuals

Comment: Thanks. That explains why they need to be adjusted, but why not just normalized them with `Dist_micm - min(Dist_micm)`? Why the need for *uniqueness*? Or is the actual value of `Dist` not important, just that it appears somewhere near the expected `Dist` location on some axis somewhere?

Comment: I guess uniqueness is the wrong word here, as the first piece of code you suggested does exactly what I need it to. What I meant in terms of unique is that when binning the data I ended up with two 1s and two 2s etc in the `df_bin`, which isn't great